# match line begin make a character to be ignored

Tags: regex, vbscript

I am trying to split alphanumeric string.

Few examples of the string and the desired match strings are:

```
"AB34C5" : "AB", "34"  , "C"  , "5"
"267BC"  : ""  , "267" , "BC"
"34"     : ""  , "34"
"QR"     : "QR"
```

I am trying to use following code:

```vb
Dim oReg, mch
Set oReg = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
oReg.Global = True
oReg.Pattern = "(^\D*)|\D+|\d+"
set mch = oReg.Execute("267BC")
```

But the result matches are : ""  , "67" , "BC"

The second match should be "267", but it skips the character "2". Why?

Comment: `2` is skipped because the first match is an empty string (found with `^\D*` part). The regex engine forces the regex index to go past the current character if the match is an empty string.  The same "problem" is with JS RegExp.

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply, now i learned why it happened. And i also wonder if there is any workaround by using different pattern to get the desired results?

Comment: I am sure you cannot do it with a single regex. I suggest adding a separate check, or even the second regex. We cannot redefine the RegExp engine behavior, sorry.